# Why doesn't android studio (mac) recognize abstract method from superclass?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, opengl-es-2.0

While working through OpenGL training on developer.android.com, android studio on mac is producing errors while implementing the GL Surface View Renderer.

The first @Override below produces an error "Method does not override method from its superclass."

If removed, the class declaration produces an error that the "onSurfaceCreated" method is not implemented.

What is the problem here?

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.EGLConfig;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    @Override protected void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)  {
        //Redraw bakground color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: because you are not importing the right EGLConfig

Comment: Thanks! removed the android.opengl.EGLConfig, added import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig; everything is working now